# Kusto convert Bytes to MeBytes by division

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

Trying to graph Bandwidth consumed using Azure Log Analytics

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where CounterName contains "Network Send"
| summarize sum(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), _ResourceId 
| render timechart
```

This generates a reasonable chart except the y axis runs from 0 - 15,000,000,000.  I tried

```
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where CounterName contains "Network Send"
| extend MeB_bandwidth_out = todouble(CounterValue)/1,048,576 
| summarize sum(MeB_bandwidth_out) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), _ResourceId 
| render timechart
```

but I get exactly the same chart.  I've tried without the todouble(), or doing it after the division, but nothing changes.  Any hint why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hard to say without seeing a sample of the data, but here are a couple of idea:

1. Try removing the commas from `1,048,576`
2. If this doesn't work, remove the last line from both queries and compare the results, and run them to see why the data doesn't make sense

P.S.  Regardless, there's a good chance that you can replace `contains` with `has` to significantly improve the performance (note that `has` looks for full words, while `contains` doesn't - so they are not the same, be careful).

Comment: It was the commas.  Obvious once someone points it out.  Thanks.